# ggplot2 is removing numbers after a custom axis transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to make a Van't Hoff plot, lnK (equillibrium constant) as a function of 1/Temperature (Kelvin). However, I want to leave the x-axis numbers in a unit that people find intuitive (Celsius) instead of inverse Kelvin. Thus, defining a custom transformation that I can pass to scale_x_continuous seemed ideal. This works fine for a 1/Temp in Celsius transformation.

```r
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

# Data:

df = data.frame(
  "Temperature" = c(25, 31, 37, 43, 49),
  "K" = c(3900, 4300, 3600, 7000, 6100)
)

# 1/Temp transformation function:

one_over_trans = function() trans_new("one_over", function(x) 1/(x), function(x) 1/(x))

# ggplot2 code:

ggplot(df, aes(x = Temperature, y = K)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "one_over") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log")
```

Result:

[image: Image with axis numbers]

However, the axis does not show numbers when I use the Celsius to Kelvin transformation

```r
one_over_trans = function() trans_new("one_over", function(x) 1/(x + 273.15), function(x) 1/(x  + 273.15))
```

Result of 1/(Celsius + 273.15):

[image: Image without axis numbers]

Any advice for showing numbers on the 1/(x+273.15) transformed axis without converting the values in the data frame?

Comment: In the `trans_new()` call, your `transform` is the same as `inverse`, which should only be true for identity transformations.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the arguments of the trans_new call. The first argument is the name of the transformation, the second argument is the transformation, the third argument is the inverse of the transformation. My transformation (1/(x+273.15)) works well when I provide the inverse of my transformation ((1/x) - 273.15).

`one_over_trans = function() trans_new("one_over", function(x) 1/(x + 273.15), function(x)((1/x)  - 273.15))`